# Swift - Modify NSURLRequest in UIWebView

Tags: swift, url, parameters, uiwebview, nsurlrequest

I created an UIWebView where i appended a parameter to the url:

```
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/?apptype=native")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    WebView.loadRequest(request)
```

When i load the first page in my UIWebView the parameter exists and i can get it using php.

But when i switch to another page the parameter disappears and i cant get it from the url using php on server-side.

So i found this delegate method:

```
func webView(WebViewNews: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

But how can i append the parameter everytime a new page is loaded in the UIWebView ??

Greetings and Thanks!

Comment: is it even possible to append a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You can return false, then retrieve the content yourself using `NSURLSession` (or `NSURLConnection`), and then inject the page into the web view by calling its `loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:` method.

This approach will only work for page loads, though, not for other resources loaded by the page (CSS, JavaScript, etc.).

For a more complete approach, you can write a custom NSURLProtocol class.  As long as you register that protocol globally, this approach should work for UIWebView classes.  You might have to register the protocol class before you create the web view.

In your custom protocol, when you are asked to start a connection, you first make a mutable copy of the request and modify it in whatever way you want to modify it.  Then, you tag the request in a custom way by calling setProperty:forKey:inRequest:, and finally, you re-issue the request using either NSURLConnection or NSURLSession.

In your canInitWithRequest: method, check to see if the request has already been tagged, and if so, return NO so that the normal HTTP/HTTPS protocol class will handle the request.